# Apply smiley replacement filter to Pandoc but not in code segments

Tags: parsing, haskell

I wrote a filter for pandas that converts `:-)` to `☺` but not in inline code or code blocks. Pandoc makes it so the `applyExceptOnCodeBlock smileyfy` function trickles through the whole tree. But since I operate on `Block`s and `Inline`s I need to handle every data constructor for `Block` that takes `Inline`s.

```
import Text.Pandoc.JSON
import Text.Pandoc.Walk

import Data.List (intercalate)
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter $ applyExceptOnCodeBlock smileyfy

smileyfy :: String -> String
smileyfy = intercalate "☺" . splitOn ":-)"


applyExceptOnCodeInline :: (String -> String) -> Inline -> Inline
applyExceptOnCodeInline f (Str s)       = Str (f s)
applyExceptOnCodeInline f (Code attr s) = Code attr s -- for code nothing shall happen
applyExceptOnCodeInline _ x = x


applyExceptOnCodeBlock :: (String -> String) -> Block -> Block
applyExceptOnCodeBlock f (Plain is) = Plain $ applyExceptOnCodeInline f <$> is
applyExceptOnCodeBlock f (Para  is) = Para  $ applyExceptOnCodeInline f <$> is
applyExceptOnCodeBlock f (LineBlock iss) = LineBlock $ (fmap . fmap) (applyExceptOnCodeInline f) iss
applyExceptOnCodeBlock f (RawBlock format s)  = RawBlock format $ f s
applyExceptOnCodeBlock f (DefinitionList [(is, bss)]) = DefinitionList [(applyExceptOnCodeInline f <$> is
                                                                        ,fmap (fmap (applyExceptOnCodeBlock f)) bss)]
applyExceptOnCodeBlock f (Header i attr is) = Header i attr $ applyExceptOnCodeInline f <$> is
applyExceptOnCodeBlock f (Table is as ds tcs tcss) = Table (applyExceptOnCodeInline f <$> is) as ds tcs tcss
applyExceptOnCodeBlock _ x = x --this covers CodeBlock as well
```

And thus it looks very convoluted. Is there a clearer way to express this?

Comment: For possible future visitors, I'd like to add that a small Lua filter is easier to apply, as you don't need a fully Haskell stack installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a much shorter way to express the same functionality, but I'm not sure you'll immediately find it to be clearer.

```
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

main :: IO ()
main = toJSONFilter smile

smile :: Inline -> Inline
smile (Str s) = Str . intercalate "☺" . splitOn ":-)" $ s
smile x = x
```

I think the insight you missed is that the `Block` constructor `CodeBlock` contains no `Inline`s, so you can trust the `Walkable` typeclass machinery to ignore them if your smiley making code *only* works on `Inline`s. That eliminates the entire `applyExceptOnCodeBlock` function.

Similarly it isn't necessary to include a case for `Inline`'s `Code` constructor, constructors like `Code` and `Math` contain their own raw strings and are safely ignored. Pandoc's datatypes are already structured to divide prose text from markup making it easy to define transformations by only matching on the things you *do* want to modify.

Comment: Thanks! I originally wanted the filter to ignore `BlockQuote` but when I switched to `Code` I didn't realize that I no longer had a problem.